# The real knapsack problem

Tags: optimization

Given

- the number of goods N
- positive weight of each good weight[N]
- positive profit of each good profit[N]
- and a positive number W which is the knapsack capacity.

This problem is called “the zero-one knapsack” for choosing the most beneficial goods for the knapsack of limited capacity.

### Example:

- The number of goods (items)   :   5
- Weight of each item (kg)  :   {2, 3, 5, 7, 8} which apply to item 1, item 2, ...... item 5 in that order
- Value of each item (10,000 yen)   :   {2, 4, 8, 9, 10} which apply to item 1, item 2, .... item 5 in that order
- Capacity of the knapsack  :   10 kg

Among the five goods:

```
Goods chosen            Total weight    Total value 
Goods 1, 2 and 3    2 + 3 + 5 = 10  2 + 4 + 8 = 14   <- Maximum
```

Comment: What is the aim of the contest? This isn't going to make an interesting golf per se, and scoring a heuristic is going to require either a lot of test cases or some detailed analysis.

Comment: do we also assume there is only 1 of each item, because if I take 2 of item3, I get a profit of 16

Comment: I'm sorry if the problem I just read was not clear to indicate that there is only 1 of each item.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 236 Charaters

Okay, I guess I'll bite.

```
from itertools import *
def k(w,p,c):
    n=len(w)
    r=range(n)
    return max(filter(lambda y:y[1]<=c,[(s,sum(map(lambda y:w[y],s)),sum(map(lambda y:p[y],s))) for s in chain.from_iterable(combinations(r,u) for u in r+[n])]),key=lambda y:y[2])[0]
```

#### Usage

The `k` function takes three arguments: a list containing the weights, a list containing the profits, and the capacity of the knapsack.  Here is how to call it given the example above:

```
> print k([2,3,5,7,8], [2,4,8,9,10], 10)
(0, 1, 2)
```

Meaning that items 0, 1, and 2 are the optimal solution.

Comment: Now how about if the number of items available for each item type is unlimited as hinted by Sean Cheshire?

Comment: If the number of items is unbounded then I'd have to use a different approach (e.g., constructing a search tree and solving the problem using something like BFS or A*).